# Generate all possible combinations of a 6 digit binary integer (each digit can be either a 0 or a 1)

Tags: python, combinations

I want to generate a list of all binary integers where each digit location can either be a 0 or a 1:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 0 1
....
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I know the total number of integers will be 2^6 = 64 where the top 32 integers will be the mirror opposite of bottom 32 integers looking left to right.

I'm not quite how to do this in python. I've been tinkering around but have not been able to figure out if there is a pre-built function that does this with one simple call.

Comment: The `itertools` module has a function that will do this.

Comment: Just loop over integers from 0 to 2^6-1 and convert them to binary.

Comment: @CoolBots - sorry I am using my brothers laptop and he was already logged into SO so I didn't realize I posted the question from his account - he is the one who has the high reputation. My brother is on the other side of the country right now and can't get a hold of him otherwise I could have asked him. Apologies for the inconvenience.  I on the other hand am a complete newbie to coding. Let me tinker around some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
itertools.product([0,1],repeat=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this recursively, every step split into a branch where you chose 0 and another where you chose 1.

```
def AllBinaryNumbers(s="", limit=6):
    if len(s) == limit:
        print(s)
    else:
        AllBinaryNumbers(s + "0")
        AllBinaryNumbers(s + "1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use the inbuilt bin function which converts an integer to its binary representation

```
a=[]
N=6
for i in range(2**N):
    a.append(f'{bin(i)[2:]:0>{N}}')
```

Comment: Sorry, I had the first line in the ```python a=[]``` and I tried to make it more genral with using N instead of 6 but noticed that the formatting strings do not support a variable as format specifier so easily. But did not change the line back, unfortunately. I now follow your suggestions...

Comment: Edited answer once again by including the variable N as the number of digits of the desired binary numbers.